# Adding css with jQuery based on class

Tags: css, jquery

Seeking a solution to my problem...

I partially found an answer from another thread on here, using this script

```
$(function () {
$(".myclass").hover(function ()
{}, function ()
{
    $(".myclass>li").fadeTo(200, 1)
});
$(".myclass>li").hoverIntent(function ()
{
    $(this).attr("id", "current");
    $(this).siblings().fadeTo(200, .6);
    $(this).fadeTo(300, 1)
}, function ()
{
    $(".myclass>li").removeAttr("id");
    $(this).fadeTo(200, 1)
})})
```

When an item in the list is hovered, the script fades all other items out. Original demo is here http://jsbin.com/usobe

This works OK on my site, though the list ( a grid of thumbnails) is part of a bigger slider script, which loads "previews" via ajax. When a list item is clicked a hidden section expands on the page, and the slider script assigns the list item a class "active".

When the hidden section is open I would like the activated thumbnail to remain at 1 opacity, while the rest are faded to .6, exactly as it is with the hover effect using the script above. What I am trying to achieve becomes obvious when you click a thumbnail to activate the ajax script. Is it possible to use the `active` class to make this happen i.e. if class is not `active` set to .6 opacity?

Thanks in advance

----EDIT

Thanks everyone for suggestions - I am not having much luck so far! Using the code above, would it be possible to modify it so that when a list item is clicked it holds the specified levels of opacity? That would do nicely, I think. Then I could use `onclick` I guess to fade all items back to full opacity when the hidden div is closed.

Comment: Yes.

If I understand correctly, you can set all thumbnails to .6 opacity in the CSS and .active to 1 in the CSS.

Comment: You are trying to keep the thumbnails with opacity of .6 when the hidden div shows up?

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to guess how your code work, for what I understand you should do something like this:

```
// this is the selector that gets the click on the thumbnail
$('li.item').click(function() {
    // fade all the thumbnails to op 1.0
    $('#li.item').css('opacity', '.6');
    // let the active thumbnail to 1.0
    $(this).css('opacity', 1);

    //show your hidden div
});
```

Then, when you close the hidden div:

```
$('div#hiddenDiv').onClose(function()
    // about to close
    $(this).fadeTo('fast', 1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an on click targeting the zetaThumbs li elements, set the current target to 1 and its siblings to .6

```
 $('.zetaThumbs li').click(function(){
    $(this).css({'opacity':1}).siblings().css({'opacity':.6});
 })
```